# In-context example of Javascript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, module

I've found many theoretical discussions of the Module pattern, but as a new developer, I'd like to see something in-context. Ie: since design patterns are there to help with structure, I want to see the structure.

Can someone direct me to an example of such a thing?

Comment: There are many modules patterns in JavaScript. You need to pick the pattern (or amalgam of patterns) that suit your situation. What framework are you working in (eg Node.js, requirejs, ...)?

Comment: I'm not using a framework. I'm a hobbyist, working on building a music app in-browser with the WebAudio API. Really, my main interest is in seeing any examples of how larger-scale structures work, since my code is getting messy and I need some ideas of how to organize it.

Comment: The architecture of the code will be very specific for your app. Only you can have an idea how to [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [modularise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_design) your code. The "module pattern" is just a syntactic convention on how to create such a module as a JS object with a private scope for its declarations.

Answer (score 1):

With requirejs, you load the requirejs script in your HTML, then use it to execute the rest of your code.

/example.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timeout, main = null;
            var main = function() {
                // check if requirejs has loaded
                if ("require" !== "undefined") {
                    require(["lib/jquery"], function(jquery) {
                        var h1 = jquery("h1");
                        h1.text(h1.text() + " world!");
                    });
                }
                // it hasn't loaded, better luck in 50 milliseconds!
                setTimeout(main, 50);
            };
            main();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are some (slightly) more in-depth examples on the requirejs website: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#examples